# How to discard multiple files in SourceTree?

Tags: version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am able to discard my changes in source tree but had to select 1 file at a time if I select multiple its still discard only 1 at a time.
Is there any way in source tree to discard more than 1 file at same time??

## I am using version 2.1

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally found the option in Source Tree

- Click on Reset button from tool bar
- Select multiple file you want to discard
- Click on discard button

You can also Reset all to discard all uncommitted changes

Refer the screen shot
[image: Reset option in spruce tree]

Answer (score 13):

*Follow steps to discard multiple uncommited changes in Sourcetree.*

> New version of Sourcetree does not have -Reset- button as mentioned previous answer. Thus, please follow these 5 steps for solution.

1. Right click "***File status***" and click "***Reset...***".

[image]

> 

2. **Select files**. *If you want, you can select all of them like the below image.*

[image]

> 

3. Click "***Reset All***".

[image]

> 

4. Again click "***Reset All***".

[image]

> 

5. Click "***Reset***".

[image]

> 

***Welldone..! No more 302 files to discard.***

[image]

Comment: This is the way for the most recent SourceTree, thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Mac, in some versions, I think you may find this reset button, under "workspace" -> file status (right click)-> Reset.

then select only needed files, and discard .

[image]